# gnuplot c++ interface through pipes -cannot open wgnuplot

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am trying to plot my graph real time in gnuplot from my c++ program.I have installed gnuplot 4.6 and am able to open the gnuplot.exe and plot graphs.But I cannot open the application through pipes. This is the code I have used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* gp;
  char *path = "C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\wgnuplot";
#ifdef WIN32
  gp = _popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
#else
  gp = _popen(path, "w");
#endif

  if (gp == NULL)
    return -1;

  fprintf(gp, "set isosample 100\n");
  fprintf(gp, "min=-1\n");
  fprintf(gp, "max=1\n");
  fprintf(gp, "pi=3.141592\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set hidden3d\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set pm3d\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set contour\n");
  fprintf(gp, "splot [min:max] [min:max] x*x+2*y*y-0.3*cos(3*pi*x)-0.4*cos(4*pi*y)+0.7\n");
  fprintf(gp, "pause -1\n");

  return 0;
}
```

I have set the environment variables and I get the following error.
c:program\ is not recognised as a internal or external command and operable program or batch file..

I tried running the exe with the same path.But it is not opening. Is it because of the maximum length of the string that can be given in the cmd prompt..

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Your `#ifdef` construct is bizarre, considering that you have it set up to use a very-much-Windows-only path only if *not* Windows.

Comment: okay.. I have downloaded a library specific for windows and used it..

Comment: @Zack is there any other nice library available for this purpose..?

Comment: I do all my plotting in R with ggplot2.  I have no idea whether it is feasible to control that from an external program, but I expect it would be at least as much trouble as what you're trying to do now.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash path separator must be escaped (or replaced by a slash):

```
char *path = "C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot";
```

Comment: thanks.. now the gnuplot opens but the commands are not written to it.there are no plots appearing.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using char* path you should write the _popen function as

gp = _popen("E:\\myprograms\\ProgramFiles\\libraries\\Gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot -persist", "w");

and possibly call the corresponding data data file via this manner

fprintf(gp,"splot \"C:\\\\Users\\\\username\\\\Documents\\\\Visual Studio 2012\\\\Projects\\\\laplace equation\\\\laplace.dat\"\n");

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gnuplot-cpp](https://github.com/orbitcowboy/gnuplot-cpp) for drawing your graphs.

This little snippet solves your problem (test1.cpp):

```
#include "gnuplot_i.hpp" 

int main()
{
   Gnuplot gp;
   gp.cmd("set isosample 100\n");
   gp.cmd("min=-1\n");
   gp.cmd("max=1\n");
   gp.cmd("pi=3.141592\n");
   gp.cmd("set hidden3d\n");
   gp.cmd("set pm3d\n");
   gp.cmd("set contour\n");
   gp.cmd("splot [min:max] [min:max] x*x+2*y*y-0.3*cos(3*pi*x)-0.4*cos(4*pi*y)+0.7\n");
   gp.cmd("pause -1\n");


   std::cout << std::endl << "Press ENTER to continue..." << std::endl;
   std::cin.clear();
   std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
   std::cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Compile and execute this application on Linux with

```
g++ test1.cpp && ./a.out
```

This gives
[image: The result]