# fprintf not writing to the pipe

Tags: c++, c, gnuplot, printf

I am successfully opening the pipe i.e gnuplot window using _popen. But not able to write to the stream using fprintf. I have checked the file pointer value and it is not null. I searched many sources and used fflush and it is not working. I could not find a solution.

Actually I have asked a similar question before here    [gnuplot c++ interface through pipes -cannot open wgnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068235/gnuplot-c-interface-through-pipes-cannot-open-wgnuplot.But) reposting with some modifications.

Any suggestions would be helpful..

```
FILE* gp;
  string command = "set style data lines\n" ;
  char *path = "\"C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot\" -persist";

  gp = _popen(path , "wt");

  if (gp == NULL)
    return -1;

 fprintf(gp,command );
 fflush(gp);
 _pclose(gp);
```

I used this code without using pipes and it uses createprocess. Here also the same situation,The gnuplot.exe opens but with no output plot.

```
int _tmain (int argc, LPTSTR argv [])

{
    DWORD i;
    HANDLE hReadPipe, hWritePipe;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES PipeSA = {sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE};
            /* Init for inheritable handles. */
    TCHAR outBuf[ ] = TEXT("a=2; plot sin(a*x)/x; pause mouse; plot exp(-a*x); pause mouse") ;  
    TCHAR inBuf[80];
    DWORD dwWritten, dwRead ;
    BOOL  bSuccess = FALSE;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  ProcInfo2;
    STARTUPINFO StartInfoCh2;


    /* Startup info for the Gnuplot process. */

    GetStartupInfo (&StartInfoCh2);

    /* Create an anonymous pipe with default size.
        The handles are inheritable. */

    bSuccess = CreatePipe (&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &PipeSA, 0);
    if (bSuccess == TRUE) printf("pipe created\n");

    WriteFile(hWritePipe, outBuf, sizeof(outBuf), &dwWritten, NULL) ;   
    printf("Wrote %d bytes to Gnuplot\n", dwWritten) ;

    CloseHandle (hWritePipe);

    /* Repeat (symmetrically) for the child process. */

    StartInfoCh2.hStdInput  = hReadPipe;
    StartInfoCh2.hStdError  = GetStdHandle (STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    StartInfoCh2.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    StartInfoCh2.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    bSuccess = FALSE ;
    bSuccess = CreateProcess ("C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL,
            TRUE,0, NULL, NULL, &StartInfoCh2, &ProcInfo2);
    if (bSuccess == TRUE)
      printf("Created Gnuplot Process\n" ) ;

    WaitForSingleObject (ProcInfo2.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle (ProcInfo2.hThread); 
    CloseHandle (hReadPipe);

    /* Wait for Gnuplot process to complete.*/

    CloseHandle (ProcInfo2.hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this may help for debugging check the return value of `fprintf` if the value is negative use `perror()`

Comment: @VaughnCato I was just trying different options as in this msdn article [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298534(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @keety it returns 0x0000000f.

Comment: If `fprintf()` is only printing 15 of the 21 (±) characters in the command string, there is a problem.  Do you need to include `\r\n` at the end because this is Windows?

Comment: i tried inlcuding \r\n.But there is no change..

Answer (score 0):

I think **the problem is not with your code but that -persist doesn't do anything** on windows. Which means that the graph is never shown for more than an instant. Instead of showing the gnuplot window you could produce an image as in the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* gp;
  gp = _popen("gnuplot", "w");

  if (gp == NULL)
    return -1;

  fprintf(gp, "set terminal png\nset output 'tmp.png'\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set isosample 100\n");
  fprintf(gp, "min=-1\n");
  fprintf(gp, "max=1\n");
  fprintf(gp, "pi=3.141592\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set hidden3d\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set pm3d\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set contour\n");
  fprintf(gp, "splot [min:max] [min:max] x*x+2*y*y-0.3*cos(3*pi*x)-0.4*cos(4*pi*y)+0.7\n");
  fflush(gp);
  pclose(gp);

  return 0;
}
```

Or you can introduce some kind of wait.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* gp;
  gp = _popen("gnuplot", "w");

  if (gp == NULL)
    return -1;

  fprintf(gp, "set isosample 100\n");
  fprintf(gp, "min=-1\n");
  fprintf(gp, "max=1\n");
  fprintf(gp, "pi=3.141592\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set hidden3d\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set pm3d\n");
  fprintf(gp, "set contour\n");
  fprintf(gp, "splot [min:max] [min:max] x*x+2*y*y-0.3*cos(3*pi*x)-0.4*cos(4*pi*y)+0.7\n");
  fflush(gp);
  for (;;) { }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bownie.. I tried this code.But there is no change in the output. After the line gp=_popen(path,"w").. the gnuplot window opens and there is no output after that.It is not closing by itself. I have to close it everytime.

Comment: ..GNUPlot window says it is for windows 32 bit. Mine is 64 bit.. is it a reason?

Comment: Thank everyone..  It is a silly mistake..I used gnuplot instead of wgnuplot. it is working now.

The correct path should be this

char *path = "\"C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot\"";

Answer (score 0):

Your syntactical use of fprintf is wrong.
it's

```
fprintf(FILE,"[string literals] [format place holder]",[arguments corresponding to each place holder]);
```

and the syntax for the place holder is

```
%[format type]
```

for the format types,

```
i or d = int
e = double shown in exponential form
f = double shown in floating point notation
g = double shown in best format
s = char * (a string literal)
c = char
```

so as an example:

```
int i=5;
fprintf("i is equal to: %i\n",i);
```

would output:

```
i is equal to 5
```

the \n is an escape sequence to display a new line.

Comment: Since there are no percent symbols in the `command` string, what is used should work OK.  Slightly unorthodox; GCC will warn about it.  But not actually illegal.  The format argument only has to be a string; it does not have to be a string literal.